# Regex for finding match groups for 1 backtick and 3 backtick

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to come up with a regex that matches the insides of a backtick, either 1 or 3.

I have the following regex that works for 1 backtick:

```
`(.*?)`
```

and this one works with 3:

````
```(.*?)```
````

I want to combine them into one regex search, I've tried something like

````
(`|```)(.*?)(`|```)
````

But that creates too many match groups, I've tried `$` and `^`, but those seems to be start of a line and end of a line...

Edge case 1:

````
My SQL Statement is below:
```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
```
````

should have 1 group with:

```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
```

---

Edge case 2

````
My SQL Statement is below:
```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
```

```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 2";
```
````

Should have 2 groups:

```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
```

and

```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 2";
```

---

Edge case 3

````
My SQL Statement is below:
```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 2";
```
````

Should have 1 group:

```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 2";
```

Should put the entire block in a group

---

Edge Case 4

```
SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1";
```

Should have 2 groups

```
table
```

and

```
id
```

Comment: You could use `(?<!\`)\`\`\`(?!\`)(.+?)(?<!\`)\`\`\`(?!\`)` (with single-line mode flag `/s` set) for your "edge case", but it doesn't work for your other examples. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvJhUf/3/).

Comment: @CarySwoveland can you write this as an answer, hard to see it inline, and I think the backticks in the solution are getting parsed

Comment: Is that OK now? I've escaped the backticks so they can be seen. You can of course also see it at the link *au naturel*.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this solution doesn't detect single line backticks, like \`2343245\`

Comment: Yes, I said that. It simply grabs everything between pairs of triple backticks, backticks and all. It's just for your edge case example.

Comment: Ahh yea, you did

Comment: `(?<!\`)\`\`\`(?!\`)(.+?)(?<!\`)(?=\`\`\`(?!\`))\`\`\`|(?<!\`)\`(?!\`)(.+?)(?<!\`)(?=\`(?!\`))` works with all four of your edge cases  and with other cases [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvJhUf/8/). I had to show the edge cases first at the link because they don't play well with my examples of non-matches. For example, if I had `\`ab\`\`` before the edge cases `\`ab\`` would fail, then it would match the second backtick and gobble up characters, including newlines and triple backticks, until it finds a solitary backtick, which would be in the middle of your first edge case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture either 1 *or* 3 backticks and use a back reference at the end so require them to be balanced.

Simple version:

```
(`(?:``)?)([^`]+)\1
```

Balaced only version. (ie the number of backticks is the same at start and end)

```
(?<=[^`]|^)(`(?:``)?)([^`]+)\1(?=[^`]|$)
```

Your target (the contents) are in group 2

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Cp52mJbMghIk4T).

Comment: Thank you! This works for me... only issue is I think if you nest a 1 tick within a 3 tick, it prefers the inner nest, not a big deal tho, just an edge case

Comment: See if the latest version works for you. If not, post your edge case please.

Comment: Post a new question or modify my current one?

Comment: Modify current. It suspect your edge case is a reasonable thing to want this regex to work with.

Comment: Yea, added to the original question

Comment: Nice solution. Consider replacing the lookbehind with `(?<!\`)` and the lookahead with `(?!\`)`. It's shorter and I'd argue it reads better. I see you tested with Rubular but don't see you often where there are `ruby` tags.

Comment: @Cary I use rubular because it's the onl regex tester I had found that works when browsing on my iPhone. The others are fancier, but require a mouse otherwise they are completely unusable. I also like its simlple permalinking. As for the suggestion, I'll think about it!

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh regarding your new edge case, are there ever multiple instances of the SQL example in the one input?

Comment: Note that `\`\`ab\``, `\`ab\`\`` and `\`\`\`\`ab\`\`\`` all match in the "simple case" because there is nothing to prevent there being extra backticks at either end.

Comment: @Bohemian it's more like a someone might want to wrap a SQL statement in 3 backtick, but a SQL statement itself can contain single backticks

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh but this is critical to the solution: can there be multiple SQL statements (that may contain backticks) in the one input? Yes or no?

Comment: @Bohemian There can be multiple SQL statements, but that should be fine, since all of them will only contain backticks. I'll add some additional examples to the question above

Answer (score 2):

Here a couple ways to do that.

**Match strings**

````
(?<=(?<!`)`)[^`\r\n]+(?=`(?!`))|(?<=(?<!`)```)[^`\r\n]+(?=```(?!`))
````

Note that this regex has no capture groups.

[PCRE (PHP) Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvJhUf/1/)

PCRE's regex engine performs the following operations.

````
(?<=       begin a positive lookbehind
  (?<!`)   following is not preceded by a backtick
  `        match a backtick
)          end positive lookbehind
[^`\r\n]+  match 1+ chars other than backtick, CR or newline
(?=        begin positive lookahead
  `        match a backtick
  (?!`)    not followed by a backtick
)          end positive lookhead
|
(?<=       begin a positive lookbehind
  (?<!`)   following is not preceded by a backtick
  ```      match 3 backticks
)          end positive lookbehind
[^`\r\n]+  match 1+ chars other than backtick, CR or newline
(?=        begin positive lookahead
  ```      match 3 backticks
  (?!`)    not followed by a backtick
)          end positive lookhead
````

`(?<!...)` is a *negative lookbehind*; `(?!...)` is a *negative lookahead*.

**Use capture groups**

````
(?<!`)`([^`\r\n]+)`(?!`)|(?<!`)```([^`\r\n]+)```(?!`)
````

[PCRE (PHP) Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvJhUf/2/)

You will see that this regular expression has two capture groups. Where there is a one-backtick match the part between the backticks is held in capture group 1, and capture group 2 is not created, and where there is a three-backtick match the part between the triples of backticks is held in capture group 2, and capture group 1 is not created.